# API Question - How to create relationships and query with multiple GET calls using cURL

Tags: api, get, php-curl

I was just handed a project and not sure how to handle it. I have limited API experience, but have been able to pull the data using the code below. In this example I want to display a cruise sailing. I have an API endpoint url of https://api.website.com/sailing/123456 (example). This gives me a ton of data, but not everything i need. For example, it gives me the "supplier_id" (this would be something like 22). I want the supplier_name, so I can display "Carnival Cruise" instead of "22". Supplier_name is in another endpoint url - https://api.website.com/suppliers. This is where I am stuck. My thought is to bring in multiple GETS and then query it down. For example, If I brought in both endpoint URLs in this example and relate the two using supplier_id (exists in both examples), then I could bring in my Supplier Name. Am I way off here? I'm used to working with a DB and queries, so maybe I'm on the wrong path. Please help if you can. Thanks!

```
<?php


    /* Sample call to get cruise sailings with filter/fields constraints */

    $curl = curl_init();
    $api_endpoint = "https://api.website.com/sailing/123456";
    $api_key = "a57fecd04e71402fba73cb2e63a262aa";

    $dataArray = array(
        "start_at" => 1,
        "max_return" => 170
    );

    $request_url = $api_endpoint . "?" . http_build_query($dataArray);

    curl_setopt_array(
        $curl, 
        array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $request_url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
               "accept: application/json",
                "api_key: {$api_key}"
               )
        )
    );

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);


    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {

/* SIMPLE DUMP OF DATA
        echo $response;*/
    }


    $data = json_decode($response);
    $total = $data->meta->total;
    $startAt = $data->meta->start;
    $maxReturn = $data->meta->count;

    // Table view of data



    echo '<table border=1><tr><th>Sailing ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Supplier ID</th><th>Supplier Name</th></tr>';


    echo '<td>' .$item->sailing_id.'</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$item->title.'</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$item->supplier_id.'</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$item->supplier_name.'</td></tr>';
    echo '</table>';

?>
```

Comment: If you are getting only one result set per api request or same `supplier_id` for all records (I think which is obvious) then you can pass the `supplier_id` into another curl request. But if you try to hit curl request for each records i.e 170 then the server may time out. Or if there is rate limit on api request then making this much request is also  bad practice.

Comment: But If you have to make api request to 170 times, then store response from first api call in database. And try getting names one by one. However in this scenario you can to live display the result with names. Also check if there is an endpoint to get names by passing multiple `supplier_id` as csv in single request

Comment: Is this not a common request? It seems like it would be pretty common to have to relate multiple endpoints. I've searched and searched and can't find anything. My thinking was to do as you suggested.. pass the supplier_id to another curl request. This is just one example though. I would need to do this to pull in the Ship Name, Images, Related Deals, Itinerary Information and more.